# Merge wide mids with long df, convert back to mids

Tags: r, dplyr, r-mice

I am trying to merge a wide-format `mids` object (as a result of multiple imputation with the `mice` package) with a long-format dataframe, which contains a `time` variable. Both dataframes contain the same IDs (`id`). However, I encounter an issue with rownames when trying to merge.

```
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)

wide <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  x = c(1.5, 3, NA, 4.2, 5.8),
  y = c(9.3, NA, 31.7, 41.1, 52.6),
  z = c(101, 198, 305, NA, 499)
)

long <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:5, each = 2),
  time = rep(1:2, times = 5),
  a = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 30, 35, 40, 30, 45),
  b = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 200, 300, 350, 400, 100, 450)
)

wide_mids <- mice(data = wide, 
                  m = 5, 
                  printFlag = FALSE)
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 2

completed_wide <- mice::complete(data = wide_mids,
                                 action = "long",
                                 include = TRUE)

merged <- merge(completed_wide, long, by = "id")
merged_mids <- as.mids(merged)
#> Warning: non-unique values when setting 'row.names': '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
#> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value): duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Trying different kinds of merging like `full_join` or `left_join` from `dplyr` still results in the same error message. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Friede a `mids` object in long format, where values from `wide` are repeated within the levels of `long` for each value of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I believe is with the `.id` argument of `as_mids()`:

> ***.id***
> An optional column number or column name in long, indicating the subject identification. If not specified, then the function searches for a variable named ".id". If this variable is found, the values in the column will define the row names in the data element of the resulting mids object.

So `as_mids()` is using the `.id` column, which has 12 rows of `1`s, 12 rows of `2`s, etc.

One way of getting around this problem is to make a new id column and then use that:

```
# Reusing L Tyrone's code
long |>
  left_join(completed_wide,
            by = "id",
            relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  mutate(newid = row_number()) |>
  as.mids(.id = "newid")
```

Output:

```
Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  5 
Imputation methods:
   id  time     a     b   .id     x     y     z 
   ""    ""    ""    ""    "" "pmm" "pmm" "pmm" 
PredictorMatrix:
     id time a b .id x y z
id    0    1 1 1   1 1 1 1
time  1    0 1 1   1 1 1 1
a     1    1 0 1   1 1 1 1
b     1    1 1 0   1 1 1 1
.id   1    1 1 1   0 1 1 1
x     1    1 1 1   1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Why does the `.imp` variable get lost?